# Error in Mapbox : Only factory methods can have the 'swift_name' attribute

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapbox, xcode7.1

I am integrating the Mapbox iOS SDK using pod. I am following the instruction to integrate the SDK from its developer [site](https://www.mapbox.com/help/first-steps-ios-sdk/#installing).

But the problem is after installing the pod While tryingt to build, I can see the error as

> Only factory methods can have the 'swift_name' attribute

And I am not able to import the header file `Mapbox.h`

I have also downloaded the demo project provided in the Github, but that was also giving same error.

For now I have commented the methods those are throwing error and now my project runs successfully. But that is not the solution. So hope some one can put some light so as to resolve the issue.

NB : My Xcode version is 7.1 and language is Objective C.

Comment: update your xcode from 7.1 to 7.3 .